# Enabling close pop up similar to markers in Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think my problem is fairly simple, however I am unable to figure it out. I want to close a note pop up with an "x" icon/div in the top right corner of the note.

Currently I have this as the code. The only solution to minimize the note is to double click on it, which obviously isn't a viable solution.

```
$('.note').click(function (event) {
  $(this).find('.notepopup').show();                                      
});

$('.note').dblclick(function (event) {
  $(this).find('.notepopup').hide();
});
```

I tried changing the second part to target the '.close' div, like this:

```
$('.close').click(function (event)  {
  $(this).find('.notepopup').hide();
});
```

I am beginning to think it has something to do with the relationship between .close and .notepopup - as in - .close is within the popup, whereas .note is in a sense the parent element of .notepopup

Any help would be great. If you really want to get crazy, you can look at what I'm working on: http://www.scottefloyd.com/notewebapp/demo.php

Comment: Did you mean [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're looking for '.notepopup' *inside* '.close'. You need $(this).parents('.notepopup'); and that should get the element.

Comment: Thank you @Ancarius, that code did work, once I isolated it outside of my site. Inside the site, however, it does not work. Something else is overriding the function, but not sure what. I don't know where to start with figuring that out. I did use .toggle() as suggested and was able to get that to work, but it does not work perfectly. It works fine when the marker is static, but every time I move it to a new location it takes two single clicks to close it or open it. I imagine it has something to do with the new position & how it identifies where 'this' is. Thanks, I'll keep working.